# How can I create cutom fields in Phabricator Manipfest programmatically?

Tags: phabricator

How can I use the `maniphest.custom-field-definitions` for Phabricator from the cli? I know how to create the custom fields using the UI based on the [docs](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/), but I am trying to do this using a command line option by passing in the JSON as stdin if possible.

I am aware that I can conduct various operations from the command like like config, auth, api etc etc, but I could not find a pointer on how to work with custom fields from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command to edit the custom field definitions from a shell:

```sh
phabricator/bin/config set maniphest.custom-field-definitions "{ your customfield json here}"
```

---

Note:
This is the same answer that I provided [on phabricator-community.org](https://discourse.phabricator-community.org/t/how-can-i-create-cutom-fields-in-phabricator-manipfest-programmatically/3416). Posting it here as well *for posterity*.